# Countdown timer not working in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Since Im new in AS3 and I just converted AS2 to AS3. The countdown doesnt work. Right now the 4 digits are looping all in the same time very fast (The three digits animation is fine - ignore it)

See countdown - http://magnixsolutions.com/clients/OT/media-buys_scoreboard-redux_160x600_5-8-2009.html

AS3

```
// get the current date and time as it exists at
// this instance in time when the frame is entered
var currentDate:Date = new Date();
var thisYear:int = currentDate.getFullYear();
var thisMonth:int = currentDate.getMonth();
var thisDate:int = currentDate.getDate();
var thisHour:int = currentDate.getHours();
var thisMinute:int = currentDate.getMinutes();
var thisSecond:int = currentDate.getSeconds() + 12;
var thisMSecond:int = currentDate.getMilliseconds();

// Date( year, month-1, date [, hour [, minute [, second [, millisecond]]]])
var eventDate = new Date(thisYear, thisMonth, thisDate, thisHour, thisMinute,        thisSecond, thisMSecond);
var eventMillisecs = eventDate.getTime();

// get the current date and time as it exists at
// this instance in time when the frame is entered
this.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, enterFrameHandler);
function enterFrameHandler() {
currentDate = new Date();
var currentMillisecs = currentDate.getTime();

this.msecs = eventMillisecs - currentMillisecs;

if (this.msecs <= 0){
    play();
    return;
}

// if the date hasn't been reached, continue to
// devise seconds, minutes, hours and days from
// the calculated milliseconds
this.secs = Math.floor(this.msecs/1000); // 1000 milliseconds make a second
this.mins = Math.floor(this.secs/60); // 60 seconds make a minute
this.hours = Math.floor(this.mins/60); // 60 minutes make a hour
this.days = Math.floor(this.hours/24); // 24 hours make a second

this.msecs = int(this.msecs % 1000);
this.secs = int(this.secs % 60);
this.mins = int(this.mins % 60);
this.hours = int(this.hours % 24);
this.days = int(this.days);

while (this.msecs.length < 3) this.msecs = "0" + this.msecs;
if (this.secs.length < 2) this.secs = "0" + this.secs;
if (this.mins.length < 2) this.mins = "0" + this.mins;
if (this.hours.length < 2) this.hours = "0" + this.hours;
while (this.days.length < 3) this.days = "0" + this.days;

for(var movie in this){
    if (this[movie]._parent == this) this[movie].evaluateFrameFrom(this); 
}
};

MovieClip.prototype.evaluateFrameFrom = function(variableClip){
var nameArray = this._name.split("_");
var numberSet = variableClip[nameArray[0]];
var character:int = parseInt(nameArray[1]);
    var frame = 1 + parseInt(numberSet.charAt(character));
if (this._currentframe != frame) this.gotoAndStop(frame);
};
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message you are receiving.

Comment: I added the error message above

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you mean:

```
// There is no number type in AS3. Use parseInt to cast string to int
var character:int = parseInt(nameArray[1]);
var frame = 1 + parseInt(numberSet.charAt(character));
```

Also, there's no such thing as `_root` in ActionScript 3.0. Try this:

```
this.avgscore_mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
```

And you need to add your enterFrame like this:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);

function enterFrameHandler() {
    // Stuff in your enter frame
}
```

Sounds like you're still thinking AS 2.0!

Comment: I updated your changes and now its reading the next line of error. "Symbol 'counter_mc', Layer 'A/S', Frame 1, Line 121, Column 18 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method number.
"var frame = 1 + number(numberSet.charAt(character));

Comment: Thank you! It cleared up the errors and now its showing one line of error on the other movie clip. I updated the codes above

Comment: No such thing as _root in AS3.0. Try using this (assuming the MovieClip is added to the stage in the current context).

Comment: Yeah, I just changed it to 'this' before you posted it. No errors on this one, but Im showing the 4 digits looping too fast all in the same time. Do you think Im missing addEventListener? Error message "Symbol 'counter_mc', Layer 'A/S', Frame 1, Line 23, Column 7 Warning: 1090: Migration issue: The onEnterFrame is not triggered automatically by Flash Player at run time in ActionScript 3.0.  You must first register this handler for the event using addEventListener ( 'enterFrame', callback_handler).
"